# glBufferSubData for a single triangle doesn't work

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm trying to refactor a simple program that draws a triangle using vertex coordinates and vertex colours put into two separate buffers into using a single buffer and two calls to `glBufferSubData`.

The screen is just empty, and the only error OpenGL debug log shows is this:

```
GL CALLBACK: ** GL ERROR ** type = 0x824c, severity = 0x9146, message = GL_INVALID_OPERATION in glDrawArrays
```

I've taken a quick look at the documentation of glDrawArrays and the corresponding error, and I fail to see how I still "have my buffer object's data store currently mapped" (I am not using geometry shaders and other possible reasons for this error at all)

Here's the main snippet of my program (there's also a wrapper that I use to handle building shaders and such, it worked when I was using two separate buffers and is simple boilerplate code so I haven't included it so as not to overload the question with text but can do so if asked to produce a minimal working program):

```
GLuint generalBufferObject;
GLuint program;
GLuint vao;

/* Define vertex positions in homogeneous coordinates */
GLfloat vertexPositions[] = {
    0.75f, 0.75f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   
    0.75f, -0.75f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 
    -0.75f, -0.75f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
};

/* Define an array of colours */
GLfloat vertexColours[] = {
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
};

using namespace std;

void init(GLWrapper* glw) {
    // Generate index (name) for one vertex array object
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);

    // Create the vertex array object and make it current
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    // Generate a name for a vertex buffer object
    glGenBuffers(1, &generalBufferObject);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, generalBufferObject);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexPositions) + sizeof(vertexColours), NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    // Fill the buffer with { xyzxyzxyz rgbrgbrgb }
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(vertexPositions),
            vertexPositions);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexPositions),
            sizeof(vertexColours), vertexColours);

    // Tell the shaders where to look for vertex coordinates and colors
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,
              (void*)sizeof(vertexPositions));

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);

    // Unbind VBO and VAO
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    try {
        // call to the wrapper
        program = glw->LoadShader("vert_attrib.vert", "vert_attrib.frag");
    } catch (exception& e) {
        cout << "Caught exception: " << e.what() << endl;
        cin.ignore();
        exit(0);
    }
}

void display() {
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, generalBufferObject);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    /* I changed coordinates here and updated the buffer before, but trying to debug this, I removed this bit of code */

    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(program);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glUseProgram(0);
}
```

Here's my simple shader:

```
// Vertex shader with vertex colour attribute

#version 420
layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec4 colour;
out vec4 fcolour;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = position;
    fcolour = colour;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not binding your vertex array before issuing a draw call. You unbind it in `init()`, i.e. call `glBindVertexArray(0)`, but you never call `glBindVertexArray(vao)` in your `display()` function.

Side-note, after setting up your vertex arrays, you don't need to contiunously call `glDisableVertexAttribArray()` and `glEnableVertexAttribArray()`. You can setup the format once, and the states will remain.

---

**Edit:** OP is laying out vertex data sequentially, i.e. VVVCCC, and not interleaved, i.e. VCVCVC. So the `stride` should be `0`, as the vertex data is tightly packed from that perspective.

Additionally, you're also specifying a `stride` of `0`. So OpenGL assumes that your vertex data is tightly packed. However, your vertex data is not tightly packed, since it contains multiple attributes.

```c
int vertexSize = (4 + 4) * sizeof(GLfloat);
...
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, vertexSize, (void*)0);
...
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, vertexSize,
              (void*)sizeof(vertexPositions));
```

Comment: I've read that "The stride​ is used to decide if there should be bytes between vertices. If it is set to 0, then OpenGL will assume that the vertex data is tightly packed. So OpenGL will compute the stride from the given other components. So if you set the size​ to be 3, and type​ to be GL_FLOAT, OpenGL will compute a stride of 12 (4 bytes per float, and 3 floats per attribute)." so assumed setting it to 0 will be less error-prone and will leave calculations to the OpenGL. Is that not the recommended way? Thank you so much for the rest, you've solved the problem and helped me a lot!

Comment: *So OpenGL will compute the stride from the given other components*:  You probably have a misunderstanding here. A stride of 0 tells OpenGL that this single attribute is tightly packed. It won't take into account sizes of other attributes than the current one.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand this correctly, if I used interleaved attributes {xyzrgb xyzrgb xyzrgb}, then the stride would be 0 = tightly-packed, then, right?

Comment: I don't quite understand why in the above answer the stride is calculated to be 8 floats. Does that mean after the coordinates of the first vertex end, we need to move 8 floats for the colour of this vertex and so on?

Comment: If I do change my code to the suggested manual calculation of `stride`, then the coordinates of the vertices and their colours are completely different (the corners of the triangle are not red, green, blue anymore)

Comment: Oh, right, sorry. You're laying it out as VVVCCC and not VCVCVC, I mixed it around. So if a buffer just contains e.g. VVVVVV, then that is tightly packed. If it contains VCVCVC (i.e. vertex pos + color), then it is not tightly packed. However, you laid it out as VVVCCC, so technically yes, yours is actually tightly packed.

Answer (score 4):

The [OpenGL 4.6 spec, Section 10.4](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf) states:

> An INVALID_OPERATION error is generated if no vertex array object is
> bound

You unbind the VAO at the end of the init method (`glBindVertexArray(0)`), but forgot to bind it again before rendering.